# Site / App color schemes

Tags: color, color-theory

I have a Color scheme for an app lets say I'm using the colors from this swatch http://kuler.adobe.com/#themeID/1746892. I am about to create another app and I'd like all of the apps created by my workshop to have the same aesthetic just different colors. I would like a way to create a "twin" of this kuler color scheme you can see that the colors are positioned relative to each other in this image, If you rotated this you would have a totally different color scheme but the same Hue & Saturation as the original scheme.

Is there any resource out there that would let me take a set of HEX color codes and allow me to create different schemes that are aesthetically pleasing next to the original?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

http://www.Colorlovers.com has an app called ColorSchemer for the Mac. Basically it's a great deal like Kuler but allows you to move the base color and link all other colors to that base color. This is one thing Kuler is painfully missing.

If you aren't on a Mac (or even if you are), you can go to Colorlovers.com choose "Palette" from the "create" drop down in the upper right. Then choose "Advanced". From there you can input up to 5 colors by hex, then using the color wheel in the lower right, just drag indicators to alter the entire palette in one shot.

I've also used Adobe Illustrator for this. You can quickly set up boxes representing a palette in Illustrator, then choose all the boxes and use Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork and play with the color wheel there, after linking the colors.